# Sublime2 Plugin: how to open multiple files in editor?

Tags: textmate, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm writing a plugin which has a command creating 3 files.

I want the 3 files to be opened and tabbed in Sublime.

I thought this would do the trick but only one file is opened.

```
self.view.window().open_file(view_path, 1)
self.view.window().open_file(controller_path, 1)
self.view.window().open_file(base_coffee, 1)
```

Any insight please?

Comment: Is the source for your plugin public? I am working on a plugin that would provide similar functionality so your code would be a good starting point

Comment: @hbtest: here you go: https://github.com/apneadiving/TextmasterSublimePlugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found it:

```
initial_window = self.view.window()
initial_window.open_file(view_path,       1)
initial_window.open_file(controller_path, 1)
initial_window.open_file(base_coffee,     1)
```